# Is it possible to send LDAP "requests" via telnet?

Tags: ldap, network-protocols, telnet

I am wondering whether is it possible or not to establish a connection to a LDAP server via telnet (or some other program) and start making requests and receiving responses as I would normally do with HTTP. In fact, the question is more generic and is related to my misunderstanding of network connections and communications protocols. Let me tell you the idea I have in my mind about this topic:

All application protocols define communication protocols (that is, messages that the server is going to understand and act upon its delivery). If I know how the application protocol works, I can establish a connection to the server (daemon controlling that protocol server-side) and start communicating with the server. For example with HTTP I can establish a connection to an HTTP SERVER via telnet and start talking with him with this requests for example:

```
GET /users/pepito HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow
Content-Type: text/html
```

**I am expecting this procedure to happen with ANY APPLICATION PROTOCOL. Is this concept right??**

I have glimpsed the [LDAP Protocol Specification RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511) but I did not understand the format of the messages. I mean, I was expecting to read something like HTTP Protocol Specification;  but it was like too generic. Can you give me an example of how LDAP search could be made?

Comment: *Why* are you 'expecting this to happen with any application protocol'? Where does it say they all look like HTTP, with readable headers in lines? *Some* of them do (FTP, SMTP, ...). Even more of them don't.

Comment: Because I could not imagine other way a communcation can be established. I need to send something to the server, that something must be readable (maybe encoded, but the 'string' that is encoded is not readable in a first instance?). How are other protocols managed? Can u give me an example? Thanks friend.

Comment: You don't need an example. You need the LDAP protocol specification, and you need to be told that you can't send it manually by typing it into a Telnet client.

Comment: Why not? I think an example will be very useful to me. I mean, giving a ASN1 specification this is enconded this way and the message is this. I would find that very useful. As regard your last sentence, why I cannot send it manually by typing directly into a Telnet cliente? What If I manually encode the message as LDAP says (ASN1 BER) and I send that message via Telnet? Isn't that possible? Thanksss.

Comment: This isn't making any sense. You can't have an example of something that doesn't exist, however useful it would be if it did. You simply cannot type binary data into a a Telnet session, and you can't get it to send anything without adding a newline that isn't part of the protocol.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The LDAP RFC specifies that LDAP messages are ASN1 encoded. This means the messages are binary data in a special format, instead of text, following a special format. This makes it very hard to write ladap-queries by hand with telnet.

Comment: Mmmm thanks, i am starting to understand... So when i read the RFC, the add operation is described this way:

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.7

Can you give me and example how is that I can encode this in ASN1.

Comment: You can have a look at the ASN1 encoding examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One

Comment: So an encoded ASN1 PDU could look like this (in hex): 30 13 02 01 05 16 0e 41 6e 79 62 6f 64 79 20 74 68 65 72 65 3f

Comment: Thanks my friend

Answer (score 4):

You can, somewhat, with a little help from some command-line friends :-)

Here's a hexdump of a simple LDAP query -- it does the equivalent of `ldapsearch -x -b "" -s base objectclass=top`:

```
30 0c 02 01 01 60 07 02 01 03 04 00 80 00
30 2c 02 01 02 63 27 04 00 0a 01 00 0a 01 00 02 01 00 02 01 1e 01 01 00 a3 12 04 0b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 63 6c 61 73 73 04 03 74 6f 70 30 00
```

Save this to a file called ldap.hexdump, and then you can use nc:

```
xxd -r -p ldap.hexdump | nc ldapserver 389
```

If you want to see the output parsed, you can use unber:

```
xxd -r -p ldap.hexdump | nc ldapserver 389 | unber -m -
```

Where this might come in handy is if you can't use ldapsearch for some reason and want to use nc or openssl to test out whether an LDAP server is responding properly. It assumes that the server accepts anonymous binds to query the empty base DN (root DSE).