# how to test my ldap server url using telnet

Tags: sockets, ldap, server, telnet

i have an ldap server on my local and remote. I could telnet to my local ldap url, but i have trouble telnet to my remote.

`telnet www.ilovebears.com 389` and i get an empty screen with a blinking cursor.

is this because of some socket configuration or that the port isn't available?

Comment: As far as I see it everything is correct. Now you have to query LDAP in order to get results. What are you looking for? Take a look [Here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4510)

Comment: i'm trying to get the list of users and the `ou` attribute of each user

Comment: Ok, but I'm afraid with telnet you cannot do it. You have to use the proper dialog and obey the rules. The DirectoryEntry class of Microsoft .NET is a good starting point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send LDAP "requests" via telnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549731/is-it-possible-to-send-ldap-requests-via-telnet)

Answer (score 7):

> telnet www.ilovebears.com 389 and i get an empty screen with a blinking cursor

That's exactly what you should get. LDAP doesn't speak Telnet. All you can accomplish with a Telnet client is to establish that the server can be connected to.

If you want to exercise the server *as an LDAP server* you have to use an LDAP client.

Comment: yes i understand LDAP client is used outside code (such as `ldapadmin.exe`) but how to use it in Java thats my challenge. any thoughts @EJP?

Comment: @bouncingHippo That may be your 'challenge', but it wasn't your question. You didn't mention Java. Since you *now* ask, there are several LDAP APIs for Java, and one is built right into Java itself: JNDI.

Comment: flawless answers!

Answer (score 1):

Your directory server was definitely listening on port 389 at www.ilovebears.com; however, it is no longer.

Do you really need/want to have your server listening on an open port on the Internet?

Comment: the url was an example for an internal enterprise ldap url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but [here](http://www.adamretter.org.uk/blog/entries/LDAPTest.java) you may find a very basic implementation of a java based LDAP client, very useful for debugging.

Hint : you may use ldaps://x.x.x.x:y for the LDAP over SSL as well...

Comment: Not the best quality example, and specific to Active Directory.