# CodeIgniter - "ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server" from localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I have to work on an old application written in PHP 5.5 with CodeIgniter 3.

For the authentication, it's using an ldap connection to a private server with the Auth_AD library.

In production server and testing server, this ldap connection works successfully, but when I try to authenticate from within localhost, I get this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Filename: libraries/Auth_AD.php

Line Number: 388
```

The credentials are exactly the same everywhere.

Here's the function called at line 388 (first ldap_bind() call):

```
private function bind_ad()
    {
      // preset the continuation marker
        $continue = true;

        // attempt to connect to each of the AD servers, stop if a connection is succesful
        foreach ($this->_hosts as $host) {
            $this->_ldap_conn = ldap_connect($host);
            if ($this->_ldap_conn) {
                break;
            } else {
                log_message('info', 'Auth_AD: Error connecting to AD server ' . $host);
            }
        }

        // check for an active LDAP connection
        if (!$this->_ldap_conn) {
            log_message('error', "Auth_AD: unable to connect to any AD servers.");
            show_error('Error connecting to any Active Directory server(s). Please check your configuration and connections.');
            $continue = false;
        }

        if ($continue) {
            // set some required LDAP options
            ldap_set_option($this->_ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
            ldap_set_option($this->_ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

            // attempt to bind to the AD using the proxy user or anonymously if no user was configured
            if ($this->_proxy_user != null) {
                ldap_bind($this->_ldap_conn, $this->_proxy_user, $this->_proxy_pass);
            } else {
                $bind = ldap_bind($this->_ldap_conn);
            }

            // verify the LDAP binding
            if (!$bind) {
                if ($this->_proxy_user != null) {
                    log_message('error', 'Auth_AD: Unable to perform LDAP bind using user ' . $this->_proxy_user);
                    show_error('Unable to bind (i.e. login) to the AD for user ID lookup');
                } else {
                    log_message('error', 'Auth_AD: Unable to perform anonymous LDAP bind.');
                    show_error('Unable to bind (i.e. login) to the AD for user ID lookup');
                }

                $continue = false;
            } else {
                log_message('debug', 'Auth_AD: Successfully bound to AD. Performing DN lookup for user');
            }
        }

        // return the result
        return $continue;
    }
```

I don't think it's a code issue because the codebase is the same in localhost or production, which works. Any idea ?

Comment: Perhaps you have misspelled "localhost"? Can you show the place / config, where you have specified connection parameters, names, ports, etc.?

Comment: The ldap directory is not in localhost but in a private server

Comment: Anyway, you should test connectivity to your LDAP from your dev PC, that you call localhost? As the error says "Can't contact LDAP server". Have you tried to connect with telnet? Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242740/how-to-test-my-ldap-server-url-using-telnet